# How to preserve formulas and external links of an excel

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

I wanted to load a sheet from an excel workbook in which I could delete values from a cell range and write new values to the same cell range. The code I used is:-

```
# opening the destination excel file 
filename1 ="destination_file.xlsx"
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1)
ws2 = wb2['sheet5']

mr=ws2.max_row

for i in range(1,21):
    for j in range(17768,mr+1):
        ws2.cell(row=j, column=i).value=None
    
wb2.save(str(filename1))
```

```
# opening the source excel file
filename ="source_file.xlsx"
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]
  
# opening the destination excel file 
filename1 ="destination_file.xlsx"
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1)
ws2 = wb2['sheet5']


mr1=ws1.max_row
mc1=ws1.max_column

mr2=ws2.max_row
  
# copying the cell values from source 
# excel file to destination excel file
for i in range (2, mr1 + 1):
    for j in range (1, mc1+1):
        # reading cell value from source excel file
        c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = j)
  
        # writing the read value to destination excel file
        ws2.cell(row =i+17766 , column = j).value = c.value

# saving the destination excel file
wb2.save(str(filename1))
```

I just tried executing the first block of code where I delete the values and save it. To check if it worked I tried to open the file but excel says it's corrupted and could not be repaired. So I'm not able to open and see the file.

The destination file has several sheets with pivot tables that uses formulas and external links. I believe that's the reason why it shows the file is corrupted and could not be recovered. Is there a way to preserve the formulas and only edit the cell range that I want to?

Also I would like to know if there's a way to optmize my code to make it more efficient.

Comment: There's not a lot you can do if the file you want to edit is that big. There might be some caches you could disable but impossible to say without the file. Complex files are difficult to get 100% right.

Comment: Ok but the file is getting corrupted when I save it. It has formulas and external links. How can I tackle that issue?

Comment: How long is a piece of string? You could drop external links. Can't say much else without a file.

Comment: Well the formulas and the links are pretty long. Unfortunately I can't share the file as it is related to work.

Comment: Well if your formulas are longer than 256 characters they'll write but they'll corrupt your workbook so the string cannot be longer than that. That limit applies to other strings as well.

Comment: You'll have to do the labourious task of comparing the input and output files on your own. Good luck!